# VLC media player is not opening

Tags: video, vlc, media

I have downloaded VLC from Snap but its not opening after double clicking and I deleted it and reinstalled it from Ubuntu app store but still, i am not able to open it pls help me

Comment: You should run vlc from terminal and see what error messages you get. Please [edit] your question and include the relevant ones.

Comment: lol after restarting and reinstalling it worked thanks btw @FedKad

Answer (score -1):

Solution that worked for me was Resetting the font cache of vlc media player

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04 (vlc snap)
[Video: How to rebuild vlc font cache](https://youtu.be/miuIo_Q8VGA)